# Linq Error "Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' Join Not Found'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-3.5, c#-3.0

**What does this mean?** Ignore the return, and the get, The results will be flattened and stuck in the application mem (so this will be a set... probably)
*"Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Linq.IQueryable'.  'Join' not found.  Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'a'."*

```
private CommonDataResponse toCommonData
        {
            get
            {
                CommonDataResponse toCommonData = this.gatewayReference.GetCommonData();
                Array dCountries = toCommonData.PropertyCountries.ToArray(); //Webservice sends KeyValuePairOfString
                Array dRegions = toCommonData.Regions; //Webservice sends Array
                Array dAreas = toCommonData.Areas; //Webservice sends Array

                    var commonRAR = from a in dAreas
                        join r in dRegions
                         on a.RegionID equals r.Id
                        join c in dCountries
                         on r.CountryCode equals c.Key
                        select new {c.Value, r.Name, a.Name, a.Id };



                    return toCommonData;
            }
        }
```

dRegions/dAreas Both arrays, dCountries is .toArray()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array` is a very loose type, and doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>` etc. You could try just switching the `Array` lines to `var` (let the compiler pick the type). If it still uses `Array`, then perhaps use `.Cast<T>()` to specify the type (or `Array.ConvertAll`, etc).

From `Array` (without more information) all it knows is `object`.

Basically, `Join` is defined (as an extension method) on `IEnumerable<T>` and `IQueryable<T>` - not `IEnumerable` (without the `<T>`).

Comment: a.RegionID and r.Id type int
r.CountryCode and c.Key type string

Comment: should of been RegionId not RegionID
Oh and changed the Arrays to Var ;o) Thanks